# Not able to load angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

I just installed angular 4 and generated the project, it is compiled correctly but it is not displayed in the browser

[image: 1]

this is what my browser shows

[image: 2]

Comment: please share your files and also see if the server is stopped from somewhere in script.

Comment: More info needed. Are u using angular-cli? How are u accessing it on browser?

Comment: here is the project https://github.com/mago8889/angular_prueba

Comment: @William ,Please also share the browser console screenshot.

Comment: @William Morales at my end your given url https://github.com/mago8889/angular_prueba working fine .

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ng serve --o
```

### OR

```
ng serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

change directory to your project directory and

run ng serve --open

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0